# Pass variable from function to late stream flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get `getGrupoFav` to pass it as a variable to the `late Stream<QuerySnapshot> task...`, I tried with `get` but I did not know how to do it and I did not find a solution, I do not know if there is a better way to do it.

the error says

"Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'getGrupoFav'.
.doc(getGrupoFav)
"

```
    _fetch() async {
    final String? userID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("usuarios")
        .doc("$userID")
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      String getGrupoFav = value.data()!["grupofav"];
      return getGrupoFav;
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }

  late Stream<QuerySnapshot> task = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("grupos")
      .doc(getGrupoFav)
      .collection("tareas")
      .snapshots();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should build your code something around like below and for the Flutter code syntax please have a look at this [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/)

```
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('usarios'); 
var userID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
var docSnapshot = await collection.doc(userID).get();
if (docSnapshot.exists) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = docSnapshot.data()!; 
    var name = data['name']; 
    }
 
Then you pass this variable to the document like, 
 
var task = FirebaseFirestore.instance .collection("grupos") .doc(name).snapshots()
```

Comment: thanks for answering! I know more or less how to obtain the value as you do, but the problem is that how do I get that value from the function, since when I put the code in the main class, it gives several errors, among the errors that it showed me in the console , was to do it using get

Comment: What is the flutter version you are using?  I’m guessing you just need to do a flutter upgrade to use the latest stable (provider needs flutter: '>= 1.16.0' for the latest version).

Comment: I have Flutter 2.10, I almost always keep the latest one, but I don't know why I didn't get the value, it's all inside a class that extends statefulwidget

Comment: Could you share the full code including how you are structuring the code with class and stateful widgets?